# Ionic 5 & Angular | How to use FlexBox in modal

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, flexbox

For unknown reasons [FlexBox](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) is ignored in [Ionic's modals](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal).

The following code will render differently in a normal component than in a component inside a ionic modal:

```
<ion-content>
  <div fxLayout="row">
    <div>Boo</div>
    <div fxFlex></div>
    <div>Foo</div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

In a normal component the code is rendered as expected:

[image]

In a modal the FlexBox is ignored. The same code is rendered the following way:

[image]

Both components imports `FlexLayoutModule`.

**Question:** How can I use Angular FlexBox inside a Ionic modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be an import problem.

FlexLayoutModule and your ModalComponent must be imported and declared into the same module